# Android restrict Youtube Video to only 1 while using WebView

Tags: android, webview, youtube-api

So currently, I've pre-defined URL which I pass to WebView and user is able to watch the video. Problem is that user can also use "search" and switch to other videos after watching the one I defined. Is there a possibility to limit user to watch only one video (while keeping possibility to mute/pause/play video)? Or do I have to implement some Video Player for this use-case?

```
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.settings.useWideViewPort = false
webView.loadUrl(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like it's no longer possible to hide the video information and related videos when using an embedded player. For more information on why YouTube removed this see https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018

I suggest you take a look at the [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player) and try the `YouTubeStandalonePlayer` or implement `YouTubePlayerFragment` or `YouTubePlayerView`.

Comment: Thank you. I do believe that one of the pre-requests for this to work is that user has to have YouTube App on phone.